# Should question about nonreproducible behaviour be closed after some time?

Tags: discussion, policy

Some questions can turn out to be specific to one user's Mathematica setup (or system settings). In particular, we currently have some questions where no one apart from the original poster can reproduce the bug, even on the same OS and with the same version of Mathematica.

If, after some time (I'm thinking one or more weeks) and discussion in comments, the bug has not been reproduced and no one has answered, should we close the question as “too localized”?

---

Current examples I found (from the *Unanswered* list):

- [Visual Studio Express 2010 on x86-64: libcmt.lib missing](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2010/visual-studio-express-2010-on-x86-64-libcmt-lib-missing)
- [Mathematica as Windows Service — Problem with Error Messages](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2207/mathematica-as-windows-service-problem-with-error-messages)

Comment: The first question has essentially been resolved.  It could be closed, but never deleted, because there's very valuable info in the comments.  The second one---it seems no one has tried to reproduce the problem, so we can't say that the problem is not reproducible (actually this is the case for the first question as well).

Comment: If the goal is to get questions off of the unanswered list, why don't you make your comment into an answer, @Szabolcs, and I will accept it. Then the question can remain open in case someone finds further insight in the future.

Comment: @Lev It wasn't really an answer, even if it has helped me.  There are other, more valuable comments.  I don't think it's really necessary to get it off the unanswered list ...